# Could the Sun's magnetosphere block extraterrestrial contact?

Tags: the-sun

I was reading how certain strong magnetic fields can block or alter radio waves so bearing this in mind would it be possible for the Sun's magnetosphere to block attempts to establish radio contact from other solar systems if the signal is weak enough?

Answer (score 1):

The Sun's magnetosphere is too weak to have a significant effect on extra solar radio waves. If it did, we wouldn't have any radio telescopes as it would block the signals they detect.

Comment: Yes, but those signals are from stellar or galactic sources. Gg8 is specifically asking about extraterrestrial sources which are going to be orders of magnitude weaker.

Comment: Certainly some of the sources are much stronger, however not all. Current radio telescopes could potentially detect the radio signals that we produce at the distance of the nearest stars.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate.  The sun is very loud in several ranges of the electromagnetic spectrum, including radio.  In fact, when the STEREO spacecraft went behind the sun, they needed to very carefully plan for the reappearance so that the antenna weren't pointed at the sun.  If they were, then the spacecraft would never see the Earth.  The spacecraft orbiting at $L_{1}$ also avoid the Earth-sun line so that DSN can actually see them...